# I am using eclipse IDE. jsp code executes but servlet returns blank page

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I am a newbie in Java.
I am comparing the database values and user entered values. JSP file just runs fine but on clicking the submit button, POST request to servlet returns blank page. No alert box is shown. I have one more servlet written in another project on same pattern and that runs perfectly. I am using Eclipse 7 , Tomcat 7 and MySQL database .I don't know what am doing incorrect. Thanks in advance.

**Following is the servlet code**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/Demo";
    String USER = "root";
    String PASS = "root";

       String Id=request.getParameter("e1");
       int id = Integer.parseInt( Id );
       String pos=request.getParameter("p1"); 
       String pr1=request.getParameter("e1");
       int pri = Integer.parseInt( pr1 );

       response.setContentType("text/html");
       PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      try{ Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
           Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
           PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("select * from users where id=?");
           ps.setInt(1, id);
           ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
            int eid  = rs.getInt("id");
            String post = rs.getString("position");
            int pr = rs.getInt("priority"); 

         if(id==eid)
            {
                if((pos.equals(post))&&(pri==pr))
                {   
                    out.print("<html><head>");
                    out.print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(" + "Details Authenticated" + ");</script>");
                    out.print("</head><body></body></html>");
                }
            }
        }
         rs.close();
         conn.close();
      }
```

**My JSP file....This jsp file request POST service. I can see the brouser URL as http://localhost:8080/Demo2/response on clicking the submit button.**

```
 <form method="POST" action="miniProj">
 <h1>Valid User</h1> 
 <b>Enter details to sign the message</b><br>
  Employee Id:<input type=text name=e1><br>
  Employee Post:<input type=text name=p1><br>
  Employee Priority:<input type=text name=pr1><br>
 <input type=submit value="submit" />
 <input type=button value="exit" />
 </form>
```

**Deployement descriptor file web.xml. This is placed in WebContent > WEB_INF**

```
  <web-app>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>compLogin</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>miniProj</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>compLogin</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/miniProj</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

Comment: Post all relevant code...where is your id variable coming from? And change the servlet name to something different from response...it might conflict with the response object

Comment: Does the request reach tomcat (I assume tomcat isn't behind apache/nginx)? Which HTTP response you get in the developer bar of your browser? By the way that isn't a "redirection to the servlet", that's a POST request.

Comment: @AngeloOparah I have edited the code above. And changed the name to miniProj. Still same problem persists. Thanks

Comment: Please try what I suggested in my answer (adding  the package name to the servlet-class field in the web.xml) and let us know if that solved the issue

Comment: where is your jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the servlet-class field with the fully qualified class name of your servlet (aka include the package name).

I would also suggest to change its name to something different from `response` not to cause conflicts with the `response object`

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>compLogin</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>yourPackageNameHere.response</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>compLogin</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/response</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In addition try extracting the section of the code that "spits" HTML from the while loop (and since you are retrieving data based on some sort of (unique?) identifier `id`, I would suggest to use an `if` statement rather than a `while` loop.

```
int eid;
String post = "";
int pr;
if(rs.next()){
    eid  = rs.getInt("id");
    post = rs.getString("position");
    pr = rs.getInt("priority"); 
}
if(id==eid)
{
    if((pos.equals(post))&&(pri==pr))
    {   
        out.print("<html><head>");
        out.print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(" + "Details Authenticated" + ");</script>");
        out.print("</head><body></body></html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: @BandanaSingh When you changed the servlet class name did you refactor or just rename?

Comment: I have refactored.

Comment: @BandanaSingh well the output comes from within the if block, first add the content type with response.setContentType("txt/html"); then print those condition variables to console to make sure that the condition is true.

Comment: @BandanaSingh any luck?

Comment: @BandanaSingh That's weird: I would suggest to uncomment all your servlets code except for the output (anything would do like "hello world" or "served at...") and then add elements in one by one to see what is causing the issue. I wouldn't be surprised if you don't get any output whatsoever even in that case: I suspect that the servlet is not even hit at this point and you might have some configuration issues.